# trying to understand strace output

Tags: unix, redirect, strace

I'm trying to get an understanding of strace.

So I figured a very hands on way would be to do the following:

```
strace ``echo "1"'' > echo1.txt

strace ``echo "2"'' > echo2.txt
```

Then:

```
diff echo1.txt echo2.txt
```

And go from there.  The idea being, that if I can see the difference in the output, I can deduce a great deal of what strace is telling me.

Unfortunately, the echo1.txt and echo2.txt only contained the output from the echo, not the strace.  I can just copy/paste the output manually, then run a diff, but now I'm simply curious about what I did wrong.

Can someone help?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[`strace`](http://www.linuxcommand.org/man_pages/strace1.html) prints to stderr, not stdout. You need should redirect with `2> echo1.txt` in order to redirect stderr to a file, or just use `strace -o echo1.txt` to explicitly write the strace output into that file.